# How can I read multiple csv files from a single directory and graph them separately in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, glob

I want to read csv files from a directory and plot them and be able to click the arrow button to step through a plot and look at a different plot. I want to specify which column and be able to title it as well as I have in the code below as well.

I am able to read the csv file and plot a single plot with specific columns but I am not sure how to do it with multiple. I've tried glob but it didn't work, I do not want to concatenate them to a single csv file. I have provided my code below. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


cols_in = [1, 3]
col_name = ['Time (s), Band (mb)']

df = pd.read_csv("/user/Desktop/TestNum1.csv", usecols = cols_in, names = 
col_name, header = None)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
my_scatter_plot = ax.scatter(df["Time (s)"], df["Band (mb)"])

ax.set_xlabel("Time (s)")
ax.set_ylabel("Band (mb)")
ax.set_title("TestNum1")
plt.show()
```

Comment: A huge issue would be calling `ax.scatter` when `ax` is undefined at this point...you probably need a line `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` at some point in there. Also, you are missing a `"` in the line `ax.set_title("TestNum1)`

Comment: @Reedinationer sorry, i forgot to add that in there I have those in there. I will update it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `for` loop over all the files and use `glob` to collect them.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob


cols_in = [1, 3]
col_name = ['Time (s), Band (mb)']

# Select all CSV files on Desktop
files = glob.glob("/user/Desktop/*.csv")

for file in files:

    df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols = cols_in, names = 
    col_name, header = None)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    my_scatter_plot = ax.scatter(df["Time (s)"], df["Band (mb)"])

    ax.set_xlabel("Time (s)")
    ax.set_ylabel("Band (mb)")
    ax.set_title("TestNum1")
    plt.show()
```

Keeping `plt.show()` inside the `for` loop will ensure each plot is plotted. It should be pretty easy to search for 'How to add a title to a plot in python' for answers to your other questions.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it running. Do you know if there is a way where you can click through and see different plots and also I want to iterate the title of each graph. For example: TestNum1, TestNum2 etc respectively. I tried writing a for loop but it was writing the path rather than the title.

Comment: For the titles, you can split the file name like `title = files.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]` to select the name of the csv file.

Comment: where would that go in the code? I have been trying to figure it out

Comment: `ax.set_title(title)`

Comment: @Dean If you want to get fancy, you can look up string formatting in Python.

Comment: Does the title declaration happen in the loop or is that outside?

Comment: @Dean If you want it on each plot, inside.

Comment: do you know of a way to create subplots on the same page? I want to use the subplots method in matplotlib but am a little confused. The research I did says to specify how many plots I want, but I need it to be n, for there can be multiple csv files in a single directory.

Comment: @Dean If the question hasn't been asked before, go ahead and create a new question. But I think there are some similar questions out there already. To nudge you in what I think is the right direction (you'll get better help if you ask a new question), you'll want to use a `for` loop and plot on the same axis `ax`.

Comment: stack overflow is not letting me ask a question. Anyway you could help me?